# Getting Correct Accuracy Per Epoch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am running SGD over a batch of data being fed by below:

```
my_dataset = data.TensorDataset(train_x,train_y) 
trainloader = data.DataLoader(my_dataset,batch_size=32,
                                      shuffle=True)
```

This is my model and loss function:

```
net = Net(n_x, n_h, n_y)
criterion = nn.BCELoss() 
optimizer = optim.ASGD(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

after defining my model and the loss function I run the code below for the training phase:

```
for epoch in range(2):
count=0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        preds = outputs > 0.5
        nb_correct = (preds == labels).sum()
        count+=nb_correct.item()   
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()



print('Finished Training')
```

The problem is I cannot find a good way to find the accuracy per epoch. Initially, my goal was to use the found method I came up with and divide the count by the size of my dataset (happens to be 209 test cases). However to my surprise diving by the dataset length results in strange outputs. What is a good way to get an accuracy percentage epoch given the way I have defined my problem?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. Just an annoying copy/paste error. But the code still has the same problem.

Comment: Yes.Thank you for the reminder.I added that part to the code as well.

Comment: Okay, last thing. Can you specify what type of weird results you're getting? Without testing this it seems like using `epoch_acc = count / float(len(trainloader.dataset))` after the inner for-loop should give you the per-epoch accuracy.

Comment: Very very low, around 20 percent :(

Comment: And you're sure that's incorrect? It does seem worse than random but may be an issue with your model.

Comment: I don't think the model is "that" bad, furthermore, I am constrained by a specific architecture that I have to follow (Relu->Sigmoid) so I cannot do any better than that. I have just put a dropout and playing around with batch sizes/learning rate to see if I can do any better

Comment: It might be worthwhile printing out the labels and preds and verifying manually that the accuracy numbers you're getting are incorrect. I'm guessing the error is elsewhere. Depending on the version of pytorch you're using you many also need to do some additional casting, can you try `nb_correct = (preds.long() == labels.long()).long().sum()`? Though TBH I would expect an error if the types were incompatible.

Comment: I will print the labels after posting this comment, regarding the  ' nb_correct = (preds.long() == labels.long()).long().sum() '  you mentioned it worked fine and without any problems. Given that my task is a simple cat/no cat classifier I don't understand why the training accuracy is so low.

Comment: I have updated with the print statements.

Comment: Based on the results you showed the dimensions of your network output have an extra unitary dimension on the end. This results in unexpected broadcasting semantics. Add the following line **before** computing loss to make sure you have the properly sized inputs to both loss and to the accuracy calculation: `outputs = outputs.view(-1)`. Alternatively you can make sure your network outputs a 1-D tensor.